# How can you measure the caffeine content of a liquid at home?

Tags: caffeine

I saw a question on here about cold brew vs hot brew caffeine content and was wondering what is the easiest (or best) way to measure this at home (if possible)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you can find [Ethyl Acetate](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Ethyl_acetate) (some nail polish removers), you can probably do [this](http://www.scienceteacherprogram.org/chemistry/Paul00-2.html).

Comment: this is exactly the kind of hacky stack overflow answer i was looking for... since you can measure the caffeine as a solid left afterwards, you can actually compare results... or rub it on your gums.

Comment: I wouldn't eat it. I doubt it is too pure (bicarbonate, sulfate, and impurities in NP remover), but do whatever makes you happy.

Comment: The experiment you link to doesn't mention ethyl acetate.  It does however require dichloromethane, sodium sulfate, and a fume hood, which you may or may not have lying around the house.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think anything short of [HPLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-performance_liquid_chromatography) or [extraction and purification](https://web.archive.org/web/20110224144950/http://www.newton.dep.anl.gov/askasci/chem00/chem00291.htm) will give you a precise result.  If you'd be ok with more of a rough idea of whether something has a lot or a little caffeine, there are [test strips available.](http://www.discovertesting.com/articles/100,1.html)

Comment: I've done simpler extractions than that... I'll have to find the procedure.

Comment: Test strips - nice!

Comment: Test strips are not available anymore. Starbucks probably made sure of that.